# error while using the resize function in vhdl

Tags: vhdl

I am trying to program an FPU unit in VHDL. I am doing my first steps. I get two errors while executing this instruction:
`mantissa1 <= std_logic_vector(resize(unsigned(mantissa1),mantissa1'length + d));`

The errors are:

```
Error: C:/Modeltech_pe_edu_10.4a/examples/fpu/shifter.vhd(38): Illegal type conversion to ieee.std_logic_1164.STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (operand type is not known).

Error: C:/Modeltech_pe_edu_10.4a/examples/fpu/shifter.vhd(36): (vcom-1078) Identifier "unsigned" is not directly visible.
```

Here is my code

```
library ieee;

USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
USE ieee.std_logic_misc.ALL;
USE ieee.std_logic_unsigned.ALL;
USE ieee.std_logic_arith.ALL;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity fpu is 
port (
    E1,E2 : IN std_logic_vector( 30 downto 23);
    M1,M2 : IN std_logic_vector( 22 downto 0);
    S1,S2 : IN std_logic_vector (31 downto 31);
    op    : IN std_logic_vector (1 downto 0);
    SUM    : OUT std_logic_vector (45 downto 0);
    E : OUT std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
    clk : IN std_logic
);
end entity;

architecture arch_fpu of fpu is
SIGNAL d: integer;

SIGNAL mantissa1 : std_logic_vector (22 DOWNTO 0) ;
SIGNAL mantissa2 : std_logic_vector (22 DOWNTO 0) ;
begin
process(E1,E2,M1,M2,S1,S2,clk)
BEGIN
if((op="01") or (op="00")) then

E<=E1 when E1>E2 else
E2;

d<=abs(conv_integer(E1-E2));

mantissa1 <= std_logic_vector(resize(unsigned(mantissa1),mantissa1'length + d));


end if;
END process;
end arch_fpu;
```

Comment: In words, what are you trying to accomplish on that line of code?

Comment: I want to resize the number of bits of mantissa1  by increasing its size by d.

Comment: Yet `mantissa1` has a fixed length determined by it's index range.

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing VHDL math libraries.  I suggest you use either numeric_std (my preference) or std_logic_unsigned/std_logic_arith, but not both.

There are several other issues as well.  You cannot assign the larger (by 'd' bits) manitissa1 value back to manitissa1, you need a target of the appropriate size.  Your subtraction of E1-E2 will need some type conversion to be legal, perhaps: signed(E1) - signed(E2)

Honestly, you probably want to rethink the whole approach to what you are trying to do, especially if you expect to synthesize this code into logic.